# How big is an Oracle CLOB when stored in database?

Tags: database, oracle

If I have a table like this

```
id  |   CLOB         | Title
1   | Text,Text,Te...| Tom Sawyer
2   | null           | Illustration
```

and the "CLOB" field will often be empty. What will happen? Memory will be wasted on a null-valued string? if yes, how much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Memory" and "stored in the database" generally have nothing to do with each other; data is stored on disk, not in memory (unless you have an in-memory database).

Regardless: if a CLOB is empty, or a short string, it only uses very little space - either when stored on disk or when copied to memory for processing. There is a CLOB locator (a pointer to where the actual data is stored) that will always exist, and the actual location where the CLOB is stored. Only as much space is used as the actual data requires - there is no "huge wasted space".

Comment: i was playing around trying to figure out the size of the lob locator for an empty_lob and i'm seeing a segment of like .125MB  .. then again my maths could be wrong

Comment: @thatjeffsmith - Surely you don't mean that; a locator is just a pointer. Do you mean the size of the data, not the locator? In any case - HOW did you do that? If you think you found the size of the locator (not the data it points to), how did you do THAT?